# Getting an R Markdown Error Message - Error in fortify(data, ...)

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, data-visualization

Error message:

Error in `fortify()`:
! `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class uneval.
Did you accidentally pass `aes()` to the `data` argument?
Backtrace:

1. ggplot2::ggplot(aes(x = factor(decade), y = income, colour = sex))
2. ggplot2:::ggplot.default(...)
3. ggplot2:::fortify.default(data, ...)
   Show Traceback
   Error in fortify(data, ...) :

My code

````
  ``` {r pressure, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE}

setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path))
load("file.RData")

filter(decade == 1980 | decade == 2010) +
ggplot(aes(x = factor(decade), y = income, colour = sex)) +
geom_boxplot() +
facet_grid(cols = vars(race)) +
scale_y_log10() +
ggtitle("Race and Gender Pay Gap - Visual 1") +
labs(y= "Annual Income", x = "Year") +
labs(colour = "Gender") +
theme_bw() +
scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set2")
````

This is what my data set looks like:

```
  year sex     age income degree race     ID decade
 <dbl> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1  1981 male     34  10000 yes    white     1   1980
2  1981 male     32   9095 no     black     2   1980
3  2009 male     64  45200 no     black     3   2000
4  1999 male     50  25000 no     white     4   1990
5  1990 male     26  24500 no     white     5   1990
6  2011 male     39  46500 yes    white     6   2010
7  2007 male     40  60000 no     white     7   2000
8  1990 male     47  39200 no     white     8   1990
9  1981 male     30  20500 no     white     9   1980
10  2007 male     55  33000 no     white    10   2000
```

Any help would be super appreciated!! Thanks :D

Comment: Hi @Hrogz, could please share your data using `dput(data)`?

Comment: 1990L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2010L, 2000L, 2000L, 1990L, 2000L, 
    2000L, 2010L, 2000L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1980L, 1980L, 1990L, 
    1980L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -33398L))

Comment: Sorry it is a huge data set - not sure if that is helpful at all!

Comment: Use `head(put(data), 20)` for small sample.

Comment: your `filter` command does not have any dataframe passed to it. Moreover, after filter you will require a pipe to ggplot not a `+` operator.

Comment: df <- gender_pay_gap %>%
  filter(decade == 1980 | decade == 2010) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(decade), y = income, colour = sex)) +


Tried this, still seems to not be generating a visual in R Markdown for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs, probably need to add

```
data %>% 
      filter(decade == 1980 | decade == 2010) %>% before the `ggplot()`
```

Sample code:

```
data %>% 
  filter(decade == 1980 | decade == 2010) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(decade), y = income, colour = sex)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(race)) +
  scale_y_log10() +
  ggtitle("Race and Gender Pay Gap - Visual 1") +
  labs(y= "Annual Income", x = "Year") +
  labs(colour = "Gender") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set2")
```

Solution-based on your comment:

```
 df<- gender_pay_gap %>%  # in my sample data gender_pay_gap is called data
      filter(decade == 1980 | decade == 2010) 


ggplot(df,aes(x = factor(decade), y = income, colour = sex)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(race)) +
  scale_y_log10() +
  ggtitle("Race and Gender Pay Gap - Visual 1") +
  labs(y= "Annual Income", x = "Year") +
  labs(colour = "Gender") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set2")
```

Plot:

[image]

Sample data:

```
data<-structure(list(year = c(1981L, 1981L, 2009L, 1999L, 1990L, 2011L, 
2007L, 1990L, 1981L, 2007L), sex = c("male", "male", "male", 
"male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male"), age = c(34L, 
32L, 64L, 50L, 26L, 39L, 40L, 47L, 30L, 55L), income = c(10000L, 
9095L, 45200L, 25000L, 24500L, 46500L, 60000L, 39200L, 20500L, 
33000L), degree = c("yes", "no", "no", "no", "no", "yes", "no", 
"no", "no", "no"), race = c("white", "black", "black", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white"), ID = 1:10, 
    decade = c(1980L, 1980L, 2000L, 1990L, 1990L, 2010L, 2000L, 
    1990L, 1980L, 2000L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```